# Using map to compare lists in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Suppose that each node is assigned a list, such as [1 0 0 1] (nodes-own variable 'state'). I'm trying to compare the lists of two connected nodes to decide how much they agree, then for a given node decide which of the connected nodes has the most similar state to its own. Ultimately I want to have the nodes update their values for another variable ('answer', which is 1 or 0) to be the same as the answer of the closest matching node.

To compare the lists of two nodes, I wanted to subtract them and take the absolute value, and set it as an 'agreement' score for the link connecting the two. So for the subtraction, I tried:

```
ask links [
let subtracted-list (map - state of end1 state of end2) ...]
```

but I'm getting a runtime error here that says "- expected input to be a number but got the list instead". I was going to then similarly use map to take the absolute value of the resulting list and take a sum, but I seem to be stuck here and can't figure out what's going wrong.

Edit:

I've tried to incorporate the suggestions but for some reason I still can't get it to work. Here is the code:

```
breed [nodes node]
nodes-own [state]
links-own [agreement-score]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  ask patches [ set pcolor black ]
  repeat num-nodes [ make-node ]
  create-network
  distribute-state
  repeat 100 [ layout ]
  reset-ticks
end

;; Distributing state values to each node (ex. [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1])
to distribute-state
ask nodes [
set state (list n-values num-state-elem [random 2])
]
end

;; Network formation - Preferential attachment from the Models Library
to make-node
  create-nodes 1 [
    rt random-float 360
    fd max-pxcor
    set size 1.5
  ]
end

to create-network
  let partner nobody
  let first-node one-of nodes
  let second-node one-of nodes with [self != first-node]
  ask first-node [ create-link-with second-node [ set color white ] ]
  let new-node one-of nodes with [not any? link-neighbors]
  while [new-node != nobody] [
    set partner find-partner
    ask new-node [ create-link-with partner [ set color white ] ]
    layout
    set new-node one-of nodes with [not any? link-neighbors]
  ]
end

to update-color
end

;; Go procedures

to go
  ask links [calculate-agreement-score]
  ask nodes [update-color]
  tick
end

to calculate-agreement-score
ask links [
set agreement-score bit-difference [state] of end1 [state] of end2
]
end

to-report bit-difference [#list1 #list2]
  let subtraction (map - #list1 #list2)
  report reduce + map abs subtraction
end

;; Making the network

to-report find-partner
  let pick random-float sum [count link-neighbors] of (nodes with [any? link-neighbors])
  let partner nobody
  ask nodes
  [if partner = nobody
    [ ifelse count link-neighbors > pick
      [ set partner self]
      [ set pick pick - (count link-neighbors)]
    ]
  ]
  report partner
end

to layout
  layout-spring (nodes with [any? link-neighbors]) links 0.4 6 1
end
```

This is still giving me the same error message: "- expected input to be a number but got the list [1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0] instead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sorts of questions are much easier to answer if you give some example inputs and expected output to reduce ambiguities. However, I think that your problem is simply that you did not use [] to extract the state value. Have a look at this complete model:

```
turtles-own [state]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 2
  [ set state []
    repeat 4 [set state lput one-of [0 1] state]
    show state
  ]
  type "subtraction is: " print (map - [state] of turtle 0 [state] of turtle 1)
end
```

Since you want to compare this subtraction over multiple pairs of nodes (or actually the sum of the absolute differences), it is best to set it up as a reporter. That way, you can then use the results of the reporter as the input to a `min-one-of` statement.

```
turtles-own [state]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 2
  [ set state []
    repeat 4 [set state lput one-of [0 1] state]
    show state
  ]
  type "subtraction is: " print (map - [state] of turtle 0 [state] of turtle 1)
  type "difference is: " print bit-difference [state] of turtle 0 [state] of turtle 1
end

to-report bit-difference [#list1 #list2]
  let subtraction (map - #list1 #list2)
  report reduce + map abs subtraction
end
```

Note that I have used # to start the argument names, this is a personal convention, but I think makes the code easier to understand as you can see what is being passed to the reporter procedure. Note also that this could be done as a single line if you don't care about readability:

```
report reduce + map abs (map - #list1 #list2)
```

This also answers how to extend your code to do the sum of absolute differences if you don't want to use the reporter procedure version:

```
let bitdiff reduce + map abs (map - [state] of end1 [state] of end2)
```

Comment: You can replace `set state [] repeat 4 [set state lput one-of [0 1] state]` with `set state n-values 4 [ one-of [0 1] ]` and `reduce +` with `sum`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. For some reason I'm still getting the same error though, and can't seem to figure out why. I've added my code as well for more context.

Comment: This is a subtle error. If you print #list1 and #list2, you will see that they look like [[0 1 0 1]] with a double bracket. You need `set state n-values num-state-elem [random 2]` when setting up the state. By putting in the `list` primitive, you are actually creating a one item list and that item is a list. `n-values` already constructs a list.